# Searching for newest folder in directory brings up "." and ".." instead of the newest folder

Tags: matlab, directory, subdirectory

This sub-segment of code does identify the newest folder. However, the name of the folder identified by this code is '.'. The pathfolder is Jimmy and I have added two new folders under Jimmy. Jimmy/Testfolder1 and Jimmy/Testfolder2 as file pathways. The newest folder should be Testfolder1, however '.' has been identified as the newest folder. Based on the time stamp of the newest folder, I have determined '.' is Jimmy.

```
d = dir(pathfolder);
isub = [d(:).isdir];
dates = [d(isub).datenum];
[~, newestIndex] = max(dates);
d(newestIndex)
d.name
```

The output is as follows:

```
   name: '..'
   date: '17-Jul-2016 19:52:53'
  bytes: 0
  isdir: 1
datenum: 7.3653e+05
```

".." strangely appeared this time instead of "." for name.
Problem to be solved: How do I get this code to identify Testfolder1 as the newest folder under Jimmy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is the current folder.

`..` is the parent folder

You should avoid taking those folders into account !

`.` and `..` are always the two first output of the command `dir`.

So you can skip those folders by adding a new line after `d = dir(pathfolder);`

```
d = dir(pathfolder);
d = d([3:end]); %Skip the 2 first results.
```